# How to test when passing a variable into a javascript iffe

Tags: javascript, testing, iife

How do I test the following iife javascript within Jasmine, if I want to mock the parameter y being passed in? 
As the script files are referenced before the specs script, the y is immediately invoked before I can mock/spy on the y object.

I can create a dummy mock object on the spec runner html (or even another js file), but this then doesn't allow me to change the mock value on each test, as I cannot reference the variable checkObject, thus I cannot test a pass/fail scenario.
 Am I missing something?

Thanks

**file 1.js**

```
var y =  {
   age:25
}
```

**file 2.js**

```
var helper = (function(checkObject){
  function isValid(itemToCheck){
    return itemToCheck > checkObject.age ;   
  }
   return {isValid:isValid}
})(y);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see what you're trying to do. I think you should redesign your code. When a peace of code is not testable, it's a hint of a poor design.
An iife is basically used to create a new lexical scope to protect against polluting the global scope. In your case, you are using iife as an object factory. One solution could be to create a helper factory that takes a checkObject and return a helper object.

```
var helperFactory = {}; 

helperFactory.createHelper = function (checkObject){

      function isValid(itemToCheck){
         return itemToCheck > checkObject.age ;   
      }

      return {isValid:isValid}; // this is the helper object returned by the factory
  }
```

Now you can test helperFactory and helper object are testable. To use the y variable, you can just do something like this :

```
var helper = helperFactory.createHelper(y);
```

remember, an iife is mainly used to hide variables (create new scope). If you want to hide the helperFactory, you have to use some mechanism to make this object visible in the global scope. you can for example attach the helperFactory to the window global object like this :

```
(function(){
    window.helperFactory = {}; 
    window.helperFactory.createHelper = function (checkObject){

        function isValid(itemToCheck){
            return itemToCheck > checkObject.age ;   
        }

        return {isValid:isValid}; // this is the helper object returned by the factory
    }
})();
var helper = window.helperFactory.createHelper(y);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. It was just a very simple example, but I do think you are right about re-factoring the code. The more I look at it, the more I think I should have a function to set/get parameters or settings.  A bit like jquery ui widget options object. [link]https://api.jqueryui.com/jquery.widget/